# BizTalk Admin is slow after upgrade to 2009 (and SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk-2009

We upgrade BizTalk 2006 R2 to BizTalk 2009, upgrading SQL Server 2005 in-place to SQL Server 2008 at the same time.

The BizTalk admin console is excessively slow.  After making some change (say, adding a receive port), just refreshing the view can cause a timeout error:

> BizTalk Server 2009 Administration Console
>
> Failed to load Group
>   [ServerName:BizTalkMgmtDb] data providers.
>   (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to load Group
>   [ServerName:BizTalkMgmtDb] data providers.
>   (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)
>
> Instance of the WMI class is not found. (WinMgmt)
>
> BizTalk Server cannot access SQL
>   server.  This could be due to one of
>   the following reasons:
>
> 1. Access permissions have been denied to the current user.  Either log on as
>      a user that has been granted
>      permissions to SQL and try again, or
>      grant the current user permission to
>      access SQL Server.
> 2. The SQL Server does not exist or an invalid database name has been
>      specified.  Check the name entered for
>      the SQL Server and database to make
>      sure they are correct as provided
>      during SQL Server installation.
> 3. The SQL Server exists, but is not currently running.  Use the Windows
>      Service Control Manager or SQL
>      Enterprise Manager to start SQL
>      Server, and try again.
> 4. A SQL database file with the same name as the specified database already
>      exists in the Microsoft SQL Server
>      data folder.
>
> Internal error from OLEDB provider:
>   "Timeout expired"

or sometimes the internal error is:

> Internal error from OLEDB provider: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (PreLoginHandshake()).]General network error. Check your network documentation."

Sometimes, just expanding the Applications node, I get this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (MMCEx)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting. (System.Data)

Any suggestions as to how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured it out.  I ended up re-installing everything rather than upgrading.

I hope someone still has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

These errors appear to have been caused by "Shared Memory" being disabled in SQL Server.

(Run "SQL Server Configuration Manager".  Under "SQL Server Network Configuration" open "Protocols for [Your Instance]")

**Edit:  I was wrong.**  This seemed to help at first, but I continued to see similar errors elsewhere.  And it appears that the Shared Memory protocol may actually lower BizTalk's performance (according to the install doc.)